# django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection prueba doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, mongodb, nosql, djongo

I want migrate Django database to MongoDB with Djongo but I have this error.
I am trying to connect to a MongoDB Atlas Database.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alexsaca/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 167, in ensure_defaults
    conn = self.databases[alias]
KeyError: 'prueba'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/alexsaca/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alexsaca/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alexsaca/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/alexsaca/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/alexsaca/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 74, in handle
    connection = connections[db]
  File "/home/alexsaca/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 199, in __getitem__
    self.ensure_defaults(alias)
  File "/home/alexsaca/python3EnvDec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 169, in ensure_defaults
    raise ConnectionDoesNotExist("The connection %s doesn't exist" % alias)
django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection prueba doesn't exist
```

My settings.py is as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'decide',
        'PASSWORD': 'decide',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'prueba': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'egc-sierrezuela-2',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
        'CLIENT': {
            'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://usuario:password@egc-sierrezuela-2.fxrpl.mongodb.net/egc-sierrezuela-2?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `Django==2.0` and `djongo==1.2.38`

I have tried many djongo versions and but the errors still arises.
Also, upgrading django to the latest version is not possible as I'm using an old project.

Any idea?

Comment: please check what information ```self.databases``` have. does it have `prueba` ?

Comment: Hi there, I don't know how to check `self.databases` info, how can I access it?

Comment: print it before it is being used. ```print(self.databases)```

Comment: I printed it after declaring it in `settings.py` and i get the following error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error when did not prepare db_routers file properly ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing)).
Assume your app structure is like this:

```
your-app/
├── app
├── db_routers.py
├── settings.py
```

In your settings file you should provide path to the router:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ('db_routers.DatabaseRouter',)
```

And assume your models are ModelPostgres and ModelMongo, define your db_routers file as follows:

```
from app.models import ModelPostgres, ModelMongo


class DatabaseRouter:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        '''You dont need to define Postgres model here since its in default database'''
        if model is ModelMongo:
            return "prueba"
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model is ModelMongo:
            return "prueba"
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        '''Optional, but multidatabase relations are not really supported by django'''
        if obj1._meta.model == ModelMongo and obj2._meta.model == ModelPostgres:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        '''Here you can get app label name or model name or hints from migrations files'''
        if model_name == ModelMongo.__name__.lower():
            return db == "prueba"
        else:
            return db == "default"
```

So it should help with migration, so you will have models for mongo in mongo database and others in postgres database. And when writing and reading from databases, djongo will know which database it should use.
And if you separated application for mongo and postgres, then you could also use app labels in your 'allow_migrate' function:

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    '''If you have one app for mongo and one for postgres, then you can use app_label'''
    if app_label == "mongo_app":
        return db == "prueba"
    else:
        return db == "default"
```